# Create a new POSIXct sequence by group

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) with 3 colums : ID, Timestamps (30 sec. intervals), State:

```
ID; Time; State
1; 23:18:00; 1
1; 23:18:30; 2
1; 23:19:00; 1
1; 23:19:30; 2
2; 23:20:00; 1
2; 23:20:30; 1
2; 23:21:00; 1
3; 23:21:30; 2
3; 23:22:00; 2
3; 23:22:30; 2
```

I'm trying to increase the sampling rate to 1 second (instead of 30 seconds) per group and fill the values of the variable "state" with the previously valid one.

For that, I create a new time index by "ID" as there can be big gaps/overlaps in Timestamps between different ID's :

```
Time.index <- df %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>% 
      expand(seq.POSIXt(from =first(df$Time), to = last(df$Time),by = 1, units = "seconds"))%>% 
      ungroup()
```

It works just fine, except for the fact that it creates a new time sequence by ID but taking the first and last time values of the whole data frame and not of each ID. Any hints into how I can fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `seq.POSIXt(from =first(Time), to = last(Time),by = 1, units = "seconds")` instead (no `df$` inside dplyr)

Comment: @docendodiscimus worked like a charm. Thanks a lot ! I'm sure this is a silly mistake but the learning curve is steep ;)